# Imported attributes show in a different admin section than magento attributes

Tags: admin, attributes

I've imported my products from WordPress to Magento. There were a few attributes that imported along with my products, and these attributes appear above (and outside of) the "Attributes" panel on the "edit product" page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/edvzo.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugk1F.png

Is there any way to get all of these attributes in the same section, so editing them is more convenient? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this for a couple days, I realized Magento 2 allows you to very easily edit the display of your product attributes in the "Stores" > "Attribute" > "Attribute Set" section.